# Scala measuring compile time

Tags: performance, scala, performance-testing, profiler

In Scala, I need to profile the compile time of several different version of the same file that when run will produce the same output.

Example:

```
time scalac foo1.scala
```

- 0m6.002s

---

```
time scalac foo2.scala
```

- 0m5.784s

---

```
time scalac foo3.scala
```

- 0m6.212s

---

[This project](https://gist.github.com/retronym/86ec6ad9ccd2c22f6148) seems to do just that, but I've never done anything like this before and the instructions don't seem very beginner friendly. If I can't get that to work I'll probably use [this](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/595), but I think that the macro compile benchmark only measures the time it takes to parse and typecheck, not the time to compile the whole file.

Ideally I would like to know how much times it take from the first compilation phase (parser) up until the last phase (generate JVM bytecode) not necessarily including jvm "warm up" time.

Comment: What do you need that you can't get with a shell script made of a few `time` commands to mesure compilation, and `diff` commands to verify that every program produces the same output?

Comment: Sounds good! One thing to watch out for is that the JVM might need time to "heat up", but yeah that sounds good.